# Python's difflib.unified_diff() returns ambiguous results

Tags: python, diff

difflib.unified_diff() returns ambiguous results when a line is edited and the exact following line is removed.

Assume csv file

```
Name,Age

George,20

Ana,16

Dan,43
```

And another file

```
Name,Age

George,20

Ana,15
```

I would expect the unified_diff function to return:

```
-Ana,16

+Ana,15

-Dan,43
```

Instead it returns:

```
-Ana,16

-Dan,43

+Ana,15
```

Which is ambiguous. It seems like the line with the name Ana was removed and the line with the name Dan was edited to "Ana,15". If you apply the operations to the old file you do get the new file but you can't understand if something was edited or not.

Is anyone aware of a way to fix this?